# transferUserInfo between AppleWatch simulator and iPhone simulator stop working from Xcode 11

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, apple-watch

I have a dependent watch app that use to work fine in simulation for Xcode 10.2.1, but when I update to Xcode 11.x.x, it seem like the transfer data does not work anymore.

In Xcode 10.x.x the target for WatchKit App always trigger both iOS and Watch App. But since Xcode 11, it only triggers the Apple Watch simulator. I already double-check to use corrected pair simulators (corrected paired iPhone + Apple Watch simulators). Already checked all the `WCSesssionActivationState` to be activated, `WCSession.default.isReachable` to be true, `session didFinish userInfoTransfer` get called for the same target, but in the other target `session didReceiveUserInfo` does not get called at all.

Is there any configuration I need to do in addition? Anyone having the same issue? 
Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is the code in main App ViewController

```swift
import UIKit
import WatchConnectivity

class ViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldMessage : UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonSend : UIButton!
    var wcSession : WCSession!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        wcSession = WCSession.default
        wcSession.delegate = self
        wcSession.activate()
    }

    //MARK: - Button Actions

    @IBAction func clickSendMessage(_ sender : UIButton) {

        let message = ["message" : textFieldMessage.text!]
        do {
            try wcSession.updateApplicationContext(message)

            if wcSession.activationState == .activated {
                if wcSession.isReachable {
                    let data = ["text": "User info from the iphone"]
                    wcSession.transferUserInfo(data)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Something went wrong")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - WCSessionDelegate

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        NSLog("%@", "activationDidCompleteWith activationState:\(activationState) error:\(String(describing: error))")
    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionDidBecomeInactive: \(session)")
    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionDidDeactivate: \(session)")
    }

    func sessionWatchStateDidChange(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("%@", "sessionWatchStateDidChange: \(session)")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didFinish userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: Error?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if session.isReachable {
                print("Transfered data")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And InterfaceController in WatchKit Extension

```swift
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session : WCSession?
    @IBOutlet weak var sessionLabel : WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        session = WCSession.default
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activate()
    }

    // MARK: - WCSessionDelegate

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        NSLog("%@", "activationDidCompleteWith activationState:\(activationState) error:\(String(describing: error))")
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
        NSLog("didReceiveApplicationContext : %@", applicationContext)
        sessionLabel.setText(applicationContext["message"] as? String)
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        print("9. InterfaceController: ", "didReceiveUserInfo")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let text = userInfo["text"] as? String {
                print(text)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is weird that the `wcSession.updateApplicationContext(message)` works fine but the `wcSession.transferUserInfo(data)` does not send data to apple watch, even the code went inside `print("Transfered data")` for ViewController

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who face the same issue. I am still not able to send data with `wcSession.transferUserInfo` but it works with another api `wcSession.sendMessage`. Seem like migrating logic to use sendMessage is the workaround for now.

Reference: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/127460

Comment: This worked for me too! For some reason, `transferUserInfo` no longer works for me in iOS 13 but `wcSession.sendMessage` works.

Answer (score 2):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615671-transferuserinfo) now state

> Always test Watch Connectivity data transfers on paired devices. The Simulator app doesn’t support the transferUserInfo(_:) method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615671-transferuserinfo) now state

> Always test Watch Connectivity data transfers on paired devices. The Simulator app doesn’t support the transferUserInfo(_:) method.